# Combining two regular expressions into one

Tags: perl

I need to combine these 2 regexes 
`^.*(Completed: BALI - Job).*$` and `\b(BALI_)(INVOICES|CORRESPONDENCE|LATE_SCANNINGS)\b` into one so that it should match `"Completed: BALI - Job"` as a mandatory and `"BALI_INVOICES or BALI_CORRESPONDENCE or BALI_LATE_SCANNINGS"` as alternatives

Comment: Could you provide examples of desired matches and non-matches?

Comment: I deleted my answer as a non-likely interpretation of the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Note that it is important to write answerable questions.  As it stands, it is extremely hard to interpret your requirements. Probably, in this case, you should show some sample input lines illustrating what should be accepted and what not, and here it would help if you identified what the captures should capture in the variations you present. For example, should the input line `BALI_INVOICES done: Completed: BALI - Job finished`, match the combined regex? What about `Status? Completed: BALI - Job BALI_INVOICES incomplete`?

Comment: It should match Completed: BALI - Job BALI_INVOICES/BALI_CORRESPONDENCE/BALI_LATE_SCANNINGS. Thanks for your efforts I got it though . I used this ^(Completed: BALI - Job).*(\b(BALI_)?(INVOICES|CORRESPONDENCE|LATE_SCANNINGS)\b).*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on David-SkyMesh's answer, making the first part mandatory, the second part of three alternatives optional:

```
/ (                                                           # capture
    (?:Completed: BALI - Job)                                 # this
                                                              # AND optionally
                                                              # one of these
    (?:\bBALI_(?:INVOICES|CORRESPONDENCE|LATE_SCANNINGS)\b)?  
  )
/x                       # ignore whitespace & comments in regexp itself
```

Comment: That assumes (1) That that the optional alternatives need to occur *after* the mandatory part, and (2) that there needs to be nothing in between the two matched parts.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh: Yes, exactly. Let's see what the OP says. The question is maybe unclear.

Comment: It should match Completed: BALI - Job as mandatory and any 1 option of the rest. BALI_INVOICES/BALI_CORRESPONDENCE/BALI_LATE_SCANNINGS. Thanks for your efforts I got it though . I used this ^(Completed: BALI - Job).*(\b(BALI_)?(INVOICES|CORRESPONDENCE|LATE_SCANNINGS)\b).*$

Answer (score 1):

As the second part is optional, a `?` is appended.

```
^.*(Completed: BALI - Job).*(\b(BALI_)(INVOICES|CORRESPONDENCE|LATE_SCANNINGS)\b)?
```

Comment: This seems like it could be a reasonable interpretation of the (very unclear) question, Except that, (1) the `.*` in the middle needs to be `.*?` and (2) the `^.*` at the start is unnecessary.

Comment: Also, I'm sure the OP doesn't want sub-captures.